# PHP Doctrine and is_dir(): open_basedir error

Tags: php, doctrine-orm

I am getting an error on a third level domain:

> Warning: is_dir(): open_basedir restriction in effect. File(/tmp) is
>   not within the allowed path(s)

It occurs in:[path-to-doctrine]/Doctrine/ORM/Proxy/ProxyFactory.php on line 188

Which is:

```
    if ( ! is_dir($parentDirectory)) {
        if (false === @mkdir($parentDirectory, 0775, true)) {                
            throw ProxyException::proxyDirectoryNotWritable();
        }
    } else if ( ! is_writable($parentDirectory)) {
        throw ProxyException::proxyDirectoryNotWritable();
    }
```

On the local server there is no error. It only happens on the live server.

What do I need to change?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

it's looks your script is using that code for caching and for a security reason you can't access to "/tmp" directory directly. You need to change that directory path to new local path which your script has the needed privileges to action.

Comment: Thanks. And where can I change the cache path in Doctrine?

Answer (score 0):

The explanation provided by [bader](http://bader) is correct.

To fix it the proxy path needs to be changed in the Doctrine settings:

```
$config = Setup::createAnnotationMetadataConfiguration(array(__DIR__."/src"), $isDevMode);
$config->setProxyDir('path-to-cache');
```